# How to write "include" php code inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to stackoverflow.
I have this code

```js
if(screen.width<500){
 document.write("<?php echo 'Hello Mobile'; ?>");
}else{

 document.write("<?php echo 'Hello PC'; ?>");
}
```

**it shows only "Hello PC".**

but when I run this on my web browser, It loads the both php files.

```js
if(screen.width<500){
 document.write("<?php include('a.php'); ?>");
}else{

 document.write("<?php include('b.php'); ?>");
}
```

Why, what's the wrong? Please help me to use "**include**" with this javascript code
Thanks

Comment: You can't, because PHP is server side. You can't load additional PHP information after the page is already loaded (Not including calling another PHP file with aJax)

Comment: Thank you bro. This is the answer what I wanted ❤️

Comment: Glad I could help.